# how to set the different background image format (png and webp) of the same image in section tag

Tags: css, image, background-image, inline, webp

I have started using webp images in my site with `<picture>` tag. all set except this

```
<section class="sec-bg" style="background: url('images/bg.jpg');">
```

I don't know, how to set the different background image format (png and webp) of the same image. please give a solution for this inline CSS in the section tag.

for other images, I'm using below code

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
</picture>
```

Comment: [This CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/#using-webp-images-in-css) suggests using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) to get either CSS class `webp` or `no-webp` added automatically to `html` element. Then you can style your elements like `.webp <my-element-selector> { ... url for webp }` and `.no-webp <my-element-selector> { ... url for png/jpg }`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use JS to handle that issue. For example you can find all elements with `background` or `background-image` style on a page and after that just replace your `webp` image to `jpeg` version. So your script will look like:

```js
document.deepCss= function(who, css){
  if(!who || !who.style) return '';
  var sty= css.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, function(a, b){
    return b.toUpperCase();
  });
  if(who.currentStyle){
    return who.style[sty] || who.currentStyle[sty] || '';
  }
  var dv= document.defaultView || window;
  return who.style[sty] ||
      dv.getComputedStyle(who,"").getPropertyValue(css) || '';
};
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0;i<elms.length;i++) {
  var url = document.deepCss(elms[i], 'background-image');
  if (url) {
    url=/url\(['"]?([^")]+)/.exec(url);

    if (url && url[1]) {
      elms[i].style.backgroundImage = "url("+url.replace('.webp', '.jpeg')+")"
    }
  }
}
```

It would be much easier for you to store the same image in two formats with the same name, for example `test.jepg` and `test.webp`, in this case you can just replace image extension by using the script which I provided above.

Answer (score 2):

we can use image-set attr

```
.box {
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(
    url("large-balloons.avif") type("image/avif"),
    url("large-balloons.jpg") type("image/jpeg"));
  background-image: image-set(
    url("large-balloons.avif") type("image/avif"),
    url("large-balloons.jpg") type("image/jpeg"));
}
```

refer to it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_image_formats

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use JavaScript to serve formats specific to the client consider using the `<picture>` tag with both sources and using CSS and `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1` to push the image into the background.

To expand your example, here's how it would work:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sec-bg">
  <div class="sec-bg__image">
    <picture>
      <source srcset="img/awesomeWebPImage.webp" type="image/webp">
      <source srcset="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
      <img src="img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg" alt="Alt Text!">
    </picture> 
  </div>
 
  <div class="sec-bg__content">
    <p>Your section content goes here!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sec-bg
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.sec-bg__image
{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-indez: -1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried the CSS rule below ?

```
background-image: url('img/image1.webp'), url('img/image1.jpg');
```

Considering that both images are the same, the second one will be used if the first one doesn't exist. This way, it acts like a "fallback image".

An inline solution can be

```
<section class="sec-bg" style="background-image: url('img/image1.webp'), url('img/image1.jpg');">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but now I get a 404 response.

Comment: Did you replace the paths correctly ? If not, you can try this : `<section class="sec-bg" style="background-image: url('img/awesomeWebPImage.webp'), url('img/creakyOldJPEG.jpg');">`

Comment: Testing on Chrome I found that it loads both images, defeating the purpose of using webp.